# Content Elements + Wygwam not working

Tags: wygwam, content-elements

I'm using EE v2.8.1, Content Elements 1.6.9 and Wygwam 3.3. On my entry page, I'm receiving a blank area where the wygwam is supposed to be. Am I missing something?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ogs877ovbszipp5/Screenshot%202014-04-23%2016.48.34.png

Answer (score 1):

The issue was (even though it wasn't being used), I had another wysiwyg available to use alongside the wygwam. Per P&T docs, this causes an issue. I simply removed the wysiwyg from the field type options and this fixed the issue:

http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/wygwam-3